# How to define the action that occurs when clicking a tree view row in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

I haven't been able to figure out how to define what action occurs when clicking a row in an OpenERP tree view.  I've created a custom tree view for showing product suppliers (product.supplierinfo).  Ideally I would like to open the form view for the product.product object with the Suppliers tab active and not a view of the product.supplierinfo object (as it does now).  Is this possible?  At a minimum I would like to open a popup window containing a view of the supplierinfo with a link to the parent product.

The supplier info view (default_code, manuf_name and manuf_code are all custom fields added to the product.supplierinfo model):

```
<record id="product_suppliers_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">product.suppliers.tree.view</field>
  <field name="model">product.supplierinfo</field>
  <field name="type">tree</field>
  <field name="priority">16</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="Product Suppliers">
      <field name="default_code"/>
      <field name="product_id"/>
      <field name="name"/>
      <field name="product_code"/>
      <field name="manuf_name"/>
      <field name="manuf_code"/>
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

Supplier info action:

```
<record id="product_suppliers_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Product Suppliers</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
  <field name="res_model">product.supplierinfo</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
  <field name="view_id" ref="product_suppliers_tree_view"/>
  <field name="help">Here you can search for products by supplier information, including supplier and manufacturer name and part number. Each product can have one or more supplier sources.</field>
</record>
```

Comment: You should probably share the definition of the view and action that you use to open it - that would help understand what you are doing. The default behavior is to open the form view of the chosen record, provided the form view is actually enabled in the calling action (e.g. view_mode='tree,form')

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the view_mode.  I had it just set to "tree" before which caused nothing to occur when a tree row was clicked.  Now if I can just figure out how to open the product.product instead of the product.supplierinfo object.